# Why does typescript think I have an Error when it can only be null?

Tags: typescript, null, type-narrowing

I have this situation where Typescript is not behaving how I expect (n.b. I can't switch on `strictNullChecks` for the whole project):

```
const error = new Error("I'm and error");
const textError = "Also and error";

const printErrorMessage = (err: string | Error) => {
  const errorMessage = (err === null || typeof err === "string") ? err : err?.message ?? err?.name ?? 'unknown error';
  if (errorMessage) {
    console.log(errorMessage);
  }
  return errorMessage;
}

const errorMessageOne = printErrorMessage(error);
const errorMessageTwo = printErrorMessage(textError);
const errorMessageThree = printErrorMessage(null);
```

My hope was that the **only** time that `err` is returned as itself is if it's `null` or a `string`, but that means the return value should either be `Null` or `string` not `string | Error`.

[image: screenshot of the TS playground, with a tooltip showing the return type is string 'or' Error]

Because this function can be sent a null object, but I don't want to convert that to the string 'unknown error' I can't just let null slide through.

Here's my [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&pretty=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgJwSBMC8MxwO4wKJIoAUARAJIDkAtjAIZgAm8hCJAlANwBQoksUcAB5QCyVBhIBBADYQQdRszEluPcNBgAHBAEswIlgFk4ECLQDmcdDCKIEALhjRdYczAA++Fm3QA+GADeXDAwvBp2KMamFlYYtkjoaBhgAK7S0h6eUACemnAgAGZKiRLOeubsMAD8xY52VQB0VCZmltU19Q1gtM3tMBQpYADWYCDYYEooFNwhOkXxYlGtcD5BISFhINJwDdIg5guRLTGcwTAAvmcIcFApCBMRCEsx3JdqfJNPx5YA8ljW2j0BkW3zghwQpzCsEez0sABVsPIMID9KIjtFLEQBMI0RDuFDPrC4HCABbXWJaFzA9HLIipdKnIA) where I've confirm this happens outside of my dev environment.

Comment: Your playground code doesn't match the code in the question. In the playground, your parameter type is `string | Error | null`, but in the code in the question, it's just `string | Error`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting my question and playing around some more I found a temporary solution (not recommended, but I need a stop gap for the time being).

You can change the assignment line to have a cast (not recommended!) to get around this: `const errorMessage = (err === null || typeof err === "string") ? (err as null | string) : err?.message ?? err?.name ?? 'unknown error';`

Definitely follow the other answers if you're able to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) (I suggest enabling all of the `strict` options via `"strict": true`). The playground you've shared doesn't have it, and that's why the return type is `string | Error`. If you [enable it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&pretty=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgJwSBMC8MxwO4wKJIoAUARAJIDkAtjAIZgAm8hCJAlANwBQoksUcAB5QCyVBhIBBADYQQdRszEluPcNBgAHBAEswIlgFk4ECLQDmcdDCKIEALhjRdYczAA++Fh8wBXadJs6AB8MADeXDBRMLwadijGphZWaJHR6XboaBhg-tIenlAAnppwIABmSlkSznrmJGnpTTAA-EqNzdGOdi0AdFQmZpatbT29YLQDIzAkvmAA1mAg2GBKKCodOpW2RoPJQRGdMeog0nC90iDmO2KJQ3CcHQC+HQhwUL4Iq-EId8ncT1UsVgPz+lgA8lhrNo9AZbntLDcUI8APQo9IAPRaaj4a1+CLgABVsPIMDD9KIEgSiAJhJSEKj0dEsTi4rskpZCQALN4pLQuOFUjlwIi5AKMzHYoA), you'll get `string | null` as you expect.

Comment: Sadly I can't switch on `strictNullChecks` for the whole codebase, and I'm not sure how to do it for just one line.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Ouch! I feel for you, legacy codebases are..."fun." :-) I'm lucky enough to have only started using TypeScript after the strict options were present and commonly used. Good news that there's a [type predicate workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77481606/157247). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the answer from [@T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) is correct.

My answer:

If you want to be able to pass `null` to the `printErrorMessage` function, you should accept `null` in the function signature:

```
const printErrorMessage = (err: string | Error | null) => { ... }
```

The inferred return type will then be `string | null`.

Comment: He does accept `null` in the function signature in the playground link (not in the question code, sadly).

Comment: Without `strictNullChecks` that's not the case

Comment: Indeed, you guys are right.